# Retrieving Building Blocks from user generated Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I've searched far and wide, and I haven't found a proper solution yet.

First off, this is a WinForms application using .NET 4.0 and DevExpress.

I've been attempting to retrieve Building Blocks (Watermarks, Cover Pages etc) from Word documents (.docx), or at least user generated template files (.dotx), that a user uploads to my application, which will then be saved to a database.

I must be able to retrieve all the Building Blocks used in that file.

I have tried a lot of different ways of retrieving them, but I can only retrieve them from the Built-In Building Blocks.dotx file, located in:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033\14\Built-In Building Blocks.dotx
```

**I haven't figured out how to extract them from a user generated file.**

Here is work in progress code I've been using (many iterations so I can easily debug it):

```
private void SaveBuildingBlock(string savedFile)
{
  try
  {
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass wordApplication = null;
    wordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.OpenNoRepairDialog(savedFile);

    object missing = System.Type.Missing;

    Database.ToolbarItemsWordInsertFileData.FileData = FileHandler.FileByteLocked(savedFile);
    Database.ToolbarItemsWordInsertFileData.Id = 0;
    Database.ToolbarItemsWordInsertFileData.ToolbarItemId = ToolbarId;
    Database.ToolbarItemsWordInsertFileData.Save();

    ListBuildingBlocks(wordApplication, wordPage);
  }
  catch (Exception err)
  {
    Logger.Log(err);
  }
}
```

Next method:

```
private void ListBuildingBlocks(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApplication, WordPages wordPage)
{
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBuildingBlockTypes type = wordPage == WordPages.CoverPage ? type = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBuildingBlockTypes.wdTypeCoverPage : type = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBuildingBlockTypes.wdTypeWatermarks;
  for (int i = 1; i <= wordApplication.Templates.Count; i++)
  {
    try
    {
      if (wordApplication.Templates[i] != null)
      {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Categories categories = wordApplication.Templates[i].BuildingBlockTypes.Item(type).Categories;
        for (int c = 1; c <= categories.Count; c++)
        {
          try
          {
            //Category cat = categories.Application[0];
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.BuildingBlocks buildingBlocks = wordApplication.Templates[i].BuildingBlockTypes.Item(type).Categories.Item(categories.Item(c).Name).BuildingBlocks;
            for (int b = 1; b <= buildingBlocks.Count; b++)
            {
              try
              {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.BuildingBlock buildingBlock = buildingBlocks.Item(b);
                if (buildingBlock != null)
                {
                  //saving to database occurs here
                }
              }
              catch (Exception err)
              {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
              }
            }
          }
          catch (Exception err)
          {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
    }
  }
}
```

The WordPages parameter [wordPage] is used in the application to specify if it's a Watermark or Cover Page (it's a property in this user control).

Comment: I have tried using OpenXML as well, which doesn't seem to be capable of handling high level items such as Building Blocks.

Comment: it would help if you could provide a word file and a list of stuff you want to get

Comment: @Vadim, as in my original post, I said I want to retrieve the Watermarks and Cover Pages someone might have made. And by that, all the data. I would like to save the Building Block as an object to the database. You can have a look at any properly generated dotx file that contains at least a Watermark or Cover Page. This has been put on hold, so I'm not in a great hurry to get it finished.

Comment: On that token, when I'm back on this project I'll make a new file for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it to the current list of add-ins, then you can open it as a template for working with building blocks. Apart from changing the attached template and loading it that way, I don't see any other way of doing this:

```
    Dim app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application

    'load the file containing the building blocks
    app.AddIns.Add("\\Path to File.dotx")

    'get the object for the loaded template
    Dim template = app.Templates(app.AddIns.Count)

    'go through each building block in the file
    For I = 1 to template.BuildingBlockEntries.Count
        Dim bb = template.BuildingBlockEntries.Item(i)
    Next
```

If you need to go down the xml route, the building blocks are stored inside the package in word\glossary\document.xml which is probably easier if you are doing this server side then you wont need to work with the word object model at all, just use the [Open Xml SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/), it's pretty useful for things like this!